# Granting roles on Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, roles

I'm creating a database with oracle and php for an assignment and i have to show the use of roles. i created a new role called employee and assigned it to a new user called employee1

```
CREATE ROLE read_only;
GRANT create session TO read_only;
GRANT select ON workson TO read_only;
GRANT select ON employee TO read_only;
GRANT select ON project TO read_only;
GRANT select ON department TO read_only;

CREATE ROLE employee;
GRANT read_only TO employee;
GRANT update ON employee TO employee;
GRANT insert ON workson TO employee;

Create user employee1 identified by qwerty1;
GRANT employee TO employee1;
```

Why does using any selects when connected as employee1 say there is no such table. select * from employee says there is no table. Did i form my roles wrong or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grants appear to be fine.  Assuming that the `employee1` user does not own the `employee` table, you would need to qualify the table name in your `SELECT` with the owner of the table.  For example, if we're talking about the `employee` table that is owned by the `hr` user, you'd need to

```
SELECT *
  FROM hr.employee;
```

If you don't want to have to qualify your table names, you have a couple of options.  First, you can create synonyms.  You can create a private synonym in the `employee1` schema that applies only to the `employee1` user

```
CREATE SYNONYM employee
   FOR hr.employee;
```

or you can create a public synonym that applies to all users

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM employee
   FOR hr.employee;
```

The second option would be to set your `current_schema` after connecting.

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=hr;
```

If you have an appropriate synonym in place or if you've set the `current_schema`, you don't have to prefix the table name with the owner of the table.